# Vite.js Import js file 'as is'

Tags: javascript, frontend, vite

With Vite.js, is there an option to load the javascript file 'as is'? Without any transformations, minifying and without injecting something like `import"./_commonjsHelpers.80d8c10d.js"` to the beginning of the file.

I need an analogue of loading the raw script and just including it in the browser, like doing this with the simple `<script>` tag.

Comment: can't you just do it with a simple script tag? It's how I get jsPDF in

Comment: show more details about your .js file?

Comment: This is elFinder library (https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder). It is a legacy stuff, that has problems with jquery imports and also I need to import some other legacy scripts which are referencing to it via the global window object. All these things are broken when Vite modifies the script, and also Vite can't correctly handle exports from this script.

Comment: You can put it in `public` directory and use it with script tag via url?

Comment: @BigLiao Yes, but would be better to manage all things via Vite, and not to have to add things manually

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following plugin to `vite.config.js`:

```js
plugins: [{
    name: 'static-js',
    apply: 'serve',
    enforce: 'pre',
    resolveId(source, importer) {
      if (source.endsWith('_commonjsHelpers.80d8c10d.js')) {
        return '\ufeff' + source;
      }
    }
}]
```

Comment: Can you please explain this example and how should it work?

Comment: This plugin will add a UTF-8 BOM marker to your js file that will cause vite to serve it as is